# A problem regarding equivalent resistance between two points

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

[image]

I came across this problem in a book which has solutions for all questions except this one. I can't get how to do this partly due my doubt whether the R and 4R resistors will get short-circuited or not. I can solve the last 'maximum power' part by taking external load equal to internal resistance. 15 minutes since I started and still **not able to find equivalent resistance**. Can anyone please help me solve this along with the modus operandi ?

Comment: This will be more well received if you demonstrate what you tried and how it failed.

Comment: First, since the whole problem could not be solved using only series  or parallel combinations, I had to use Kirchoff's laws. It struck me that the plain conducting wire attached at the bottom would serve to short circuit the R and 4R resistances just above it. Plainly put, my doubt is whether the wire will actually short circuit or not. If it does, then solving the sum would be greatly simplified as even the 6R and R resistances placed vertically would play no role in affecting the equivalent resistance. This is key to proceeding with the application of the loop rule to the various loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

look at the final equivalent circuit and solve you will get c)39/7

Comment: Right answer! But in the third step, wouldn't the 2 ohm resistor be directly connected to the 4 ohm one? Thanks for taking the time anyways!

Comment: No, the point connecting 2R  and 4R is actually the common point connecting the 4ohm,4R and 2R hence we can't join the 2R and 4R in series.